# matplotlib.pyplot - enlarge section of y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use some python code to create the following boxplot. [image: boxplot]

However, as the second box is really small, I would like to enlarge the section between the first y-tick (0) and the second y-tick (20) in order to kind of zoom in. Is this possible with python? I am glad for any suggestions or help. I already looked for any possible solution but I did not find the perfect function yet (I supposed a log function though, but could not make it run properly).

Here is the code, I used to create the boxplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon 
import numpy as np

data_1 = [75, 85, 72]
tuple_1 = tuple(data_1) 

data_2 = [1, 2, 1.5] 
tuple_2 = tuple(data_2)

data = [tuple_1, tuple_2]
numDists=2
randomDists = ['tuple_1', 'tuple_2']    
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.set_window_title('A Boxplot Example')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.075, right=0.95, top=0.9, bottom=0.5)
bp = plt.boxplot(data, notch=0, sym='+', vert=1, whis=1.5)
plt.setp(bp['boxes'], color='black')
plt.setp(bp['whiskers'], color='black')
plt.setp(bp['fliers'], color='black', marker='+')
ax1.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', color='lightgrey',
           alpha=0.5)
ax1.set_axisbelow(True)
ax1.set_title('')
ax1.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('y-axis')
boxColors = ['red', 'blue']
numBoxes = numDists
medians = list(range(numBoxes))
for i in range(numBoxes):
    box = bp['boxes'][i]
    boxX = []
    boxY = []
    for j in range(5):
        boxX.append(box.get_xdata()[j])
        boxY.append(box.get_ydata()[j])
    boxCoords = list(zip(boxX, boxY))
    k = i % 2
    boxPolygon = Polygon(boxCoords, facecolor=boxColors[k])
    ax1.add_patch(boxPolygon)
    med = bp['medians'][i]
    medianX = []
    medianY = []
    for j in range(2):
        medianX.append(med.get_xdata()[j])
        medianY.append(med.get_ydata()[j])
        plt.plot(medianX, medianY, 'k')
        medians[i] = medianY[0]

    plt.plot([np.average(med.get_xdata())], [np.average(data[i])],
         color='w', marker='*', markeredgecolor='k')

ax1.set_xlim(0.5, numBoxes + 0.5)
top = 110
bottom = 0
ax1.set_ylim(bottom, top)
xtickNames = plt.setp(ax1, xticklabels=np.repeat(randomDists, 1))
plt.setp(xtickNames, rotation=45, fontsize=8)

pos = np.arange(numBoxes) + 1
upperLabels = [str(np.round(s, 2)) for s in medians]
weights = ['bold', 'semibold']
for tick, label in zip(range(numBoxes), ax1.get_xticklabels()):
    k = tick % 2
    ax1.text(pos[tick], top - (top*0.05), upperLabels[tick],
         horizontalalignment='center', size='x-small', weight=weights[k],
         color=boxColors[k])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you considered using a logarithmic axis?

Comment: How about something like this: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html